# SQL In one list but not another

Tags: mysql

Have three tables Vehicle, VehicleGroup and AssignedVehicleGroup which have the following format:

**Vehicle** - vehicleId, customerId, registration

**VehicleGroup** - groupId, groupName

**AssignedVehicleGroup** - vehicleId, groupId

Vehicles can be placed in more than one group using this schema however I am struggling to write a single query that can find :

- All vehicles that are not allocated to any group
- All vehicles that are not in the current group (based on variable passed in)

This query will populate a list that allows user to add vehicle to current group if it is not already in the current group or in any group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *not in a group* query is often the more tricky to sort out.

Vehicles in no groups:

```
SELECT v.registration
FROM Vehicle v
LEFT JOIN AssignedVehicleGroup vg ON (v.vehicleId=vg.VehicleId)
WHERE vg.groupId IS NULL
```

Vehicles not in a specific group:

```
SELECT v.registration
FROM Vehicle v
LEFT JOIN AssignedVehicleGroup vg ON (v.vehicleId=vg.VehicleId AND vg.groupId = 5)
WHERE vg.groupId IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a list of vehicles who do not have match in the assigned table:

```
SELECT v.* 
FROM   vehicle v 
       LEFT JOIN assignedvehiclegroup ag 
         ON ag.vehicleid = v.vehicleid 
            WHERE ag.vehicleid IS NULL
```

To return the vehicles that are not in the current group:

```
SELECT v.* 
FROM   vehicle v 
       LEFT JOIN assignedvehiclegroup ag 
         ON ag.vehicleid = v.vehicleid 
            WHERE ag.groupid<=>100
```

Comment: What's `<=>`? I've not used that operator before

Comment: @Cylindric It's the null safe equal http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to

Comment: 1st query indeed does what it says, but fails to take into account those vehicles that may be in OTHER groups that we may want to allocate to CURRENT group. All the query really needs to do is return all vehicles not in current group. The second query does the exact opposite -> returns all vehicles in group 100.

Comment: Never spotted that one.  Might save me a whole bunch of `COALESCE` in my queries.

Comment: @EdwardLuke it's not clear what is wrong with the 2nd query, could you please reformulate.